# Problem using processing.runandload()

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, qgis-processing, pyqt

I'm writing a QGIS plugin using PyQGIS and I have a weird problem.

When executing following line of code:

```
processing.runandload("qgis:createpointsalonglines", r"Clipped", 1, 1, 0, r"memory:nodes")
```

I get this error

[image]

However, I use this "kind of code" multiple times in my plugin, and only get the error for this line...

For example,

I execute

```
processing.runandload("qgis:clip", "parallel", "polygon", r"memory:Clipped")
```

and

```
processing.runandload("qgis:orientedminimumboundingbox", "polygon", 1, r"memory:Oriented_MBBox")
```

without any problem, in the same program.

Anbybody has any idea why ?

Also: if I define the output layer as "memory:LayerName", the layer is created but the real layer name is not equal to LayerName... QGIS always gives the layer a standard name, depending on the function..

How can I give the layer the name I want?

Comment: And what do the log messages say?

Comment: I tried checking the log messages, if I'm correct, you do this by going to processing > History ? If correct, there's nothing there to read ....

Comment: There is a balloon icon at the lower right of the main window which opens the message log. Check the tab processing.

Comment: This is what it says:

'Error loading result layer:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/Kristof/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\gui\Postprocessing.py", line 76, in handleAlgorithmResults
       out.name))
     File "C:/Users/Kristof/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\tools\dataobjects.py", line 194, in load
       + '\nCheck the procesing framework log to look for errors')
   RuntimeError: Could not load layer: memory:points
   Check the procesing framework log to look for errors'

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any requested clarifications.